# Trying To Get Jekyll To Render Markdown in my Posts

Tags: markdown, jekyll

My files in my _posts folder end in .markdown (also tried .md) yet when they are processed they are displayed as html files and the markdown syntax is not processed.

I am sure I am doing something silly wrong but can't figure it out. I looked through example Jekyll blog and their markdown is rendering fine but I can't seem to see what my error is.

[This SO post I tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275429/cant-get-jekyll-to-parse-markdown) but using {{ content }} rather than {{ page.content }} didn't seem to make a difference. My markdown in my post files still does not get converted and things like **link** or *link* just show up in the generated html.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your posts are not processed by `jekyll build` or `jekyll serve`, you may have forgotten to add a [front matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) like :

```
---
title:  "The title!"
date:   2015-09-14 23:50:46
---
```

Comment: Always had YAML front matter but maybe the {{ content }} to {{ page.content }} change worked not sure but everything is fine now.